# RESTful Mongoose with ObjectID references

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, rest, mongoose

**My Question:** How can I have a RESTful mongodb instance which uses mongoosejs without making a million http requests?

**My Setup:** I'm using [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) for the backend with [MongooseJS](http://mongoosejs.com/). I'm using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org) on the front-end, so I've decided to use [angular-bridge](https://github.com/Unitech/angular-bridge) to restify my [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) database.

**My Schemas:** I have the following schema:

[image: Schemas]

**Note:** The start of the arrow represents that object has a reference to the object at the end of the arrow (for example, `comment` has a `owningPost` property which is an `ObjectID` reference to the post). Also, the asterisks (*) means "many" so, a post can have many comments, but a comment references only one post and a stream can reference many buckets and a bucket can have many streams referencing it.

**The issue:** Let's say the user hits the page representing a bucket. I need to make the following get requests:

1. Bucket
2. User
3. Every post that references the bucket
4. Every comment that references a post
5. The user for each comment

The number of requests can explode quickly. Perhaps I could have the comment contained in the post, that may not be a problem. However, I can't do that for everything else (and stay sane).

I tried making an endpoint that gets all of the data in different properties like:

```
data: {
  bucket: {},
  user: {},
  posts: [
    {
      post: {},
      comments: [
        user: {},
        comment: {}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But then it's not longer restful... Right? It makes updating stuff a little difficult.

What am I doing wrong? What's a better way to do this?

Comment: If your data and requirements fit the relational model you might consider using a relational database instead of MongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is:

- I don't populate anything on a "list" request.
- I populate all objectId references on a "show" request.

This would not make your service less RESTful, as far as I'm concerned. It will still be resource oriented and the attached data actually belongs to that specific resource. That should reduce the amount of requests you'd need to make.

Alternatively, you could create a container resource that gathers all the required information and sends it back to the client. I'd personally go with a couple of separate requests though. Especially because, since HTTP 1.1, multiple requests can be executed through the same connection. I don't think that requesting multiple JSON objects at the same time would have any significant impact on the performance of your application.

I wouldn't nest everything inside a "data" schema though.

Hope it helps and good luck!

Comment: The more I think about this idea, the more I like it. I think I'll go with it. I'll let you know when I've tried it out and how it turned out.

Comment: @kentcdodds I'm glad you like the idea and and yes, please do!

Comment: Ok, so this is working great. You really helped me get past this even though I didn't exactly go with your implementation. What I do is I actually do return a "data" object when getting a stream's posts, but I create a `$resource` object for the appropriate data and then simply append that object on the resource it belongs to. This wont be persisted to the data object anyway. So, basically, when I load a post, it has a comments property, so I create/replace a resource for each of those then I do the same with the comment's author. This way I get the restful benefits, and make fewer requests.

Answer (score 1):

It is, to me, more like a document-oriented data design problem than a REST design one. My approach is to drive the design of data model by the view or the pages, not to design the model first then try to fit the view to it. This somehow aligns with Reda's answer.

In order to reduce the number of requests or mongoose populations, I always allow duplications in the documents. In your example, a bucket will has an array of post id's and an array of stream ids. At the same time, a post will has an array of buckets id's and even some detailed information of each bucket. Such a design will make retrieval of the document very fast, but slow down update operations, and also introduces the risk of inconsistence.

Answer (score 0):

You should denormalise your schema

Comment: I realize that a normalized schema isn't the "MongoDB way" but how would you recommend representing those relationships of many-to-many without a normalized schema?

Comment: I would store all the data shown on the webpage in a single document

Comment: I guess I didn't do a good enough job explaining how I'm using this data. Because a post can be in more than one bucket, and a bucket can have more than one post, which document would you recommend storing the other in? It wouldn't make sense either way... At least not to me. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're still reasoning in relational terms. What are your use cases? How do you display and edit this data?

Comment: There can be a post page where it shows just a specific post and its comments. There can be a bucket page where it shows all the posts/comments in that bucket. There can also be a stream page where it shows all the posts/comments in all of its buckets and all its stream's buckets.

Comment: Have you considered a relational database? All databases have their appropriate use cases.